# mongoimport failing inconsistently with "The _id field cannot be changed from"

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I have problems importing data into mongodb with. I have a `test.json` file like this:

```
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38851448"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38853194"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760498"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"39099662"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38855558"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760487"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760488"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"39099663"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38851450"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"_id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38853546"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
```

I try to import it with following command:

```
mongoimport --type json --db test --collection coll --file test.json --upsert
```

The import fails almost always with the same error message:

```
2015-08-27T17:02:15.510+0200    error inserting documents: The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: { s: 38851448, a: 5 }} to {_id: { a: 5, s: 38851448 }}.
2015-08-27T17:02:15.511+0200    error inserting documents: The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: { a: 5, s: 38760487 }} to {_id: { s: 38760487, a: 5 }}.
```

It's frustrating that this error isn't even reproducable. The importer seems to change the order of the properties for `_id`, but I don't know why, is this a BUG that should be reported or is already known? Or is there 
a problem I don't see.

I even tried to change the order of `s` and  `a` in `_id`, but the problem stays the same.

If I trie to run the exact same import command with exactly the same datafile multiple times the documents with errors change and one time it imported all rows as expected, but just one time:

[image]

For completeness: I'm using mongo 3.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.10.5 installed by homebrew.

**UPDATE**:
I have created a Ticket with mongoDB-Team: [TOOLS-894](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-894)

**UPDATE2**:

I tried not to use _id but id for my unique key:

```
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38851448"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38853194"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760498"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"39099662"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38855558"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760487"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760488"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"39099663"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38851450"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
{"id":{"s":{"$numberLong":"38853546"},"a":5},"someKey":"someValue"}
```

and import this with:

```
mongoimport --type json --db test --collection coll --file test.json --upsertFields id
```

Now I don't get any errors, but after two imports I have 15 rows in the collection instead of 10. Again because of the order of the properties in `id`.

Comment: Seems like `--upsert` flag is causing this error, is it necessary in your case. Seems like mongo causes problem when it tries to update the data with the composite id.

Comment: yes the upsert is necessary, because the JSON-file I get is a dump from another (non-MongoDB) system and contains new and updated documents, so the upsert is mandatory, because without it, it would fail to import with `E11000 duplicate key error collection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things I tried lead me to believe that this is a bug within `mongoimport` and I reported it to the mongoldb team: [TOOLS-894](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-894)

The workaround that's working for me is to move the the unique key for documents out of `_id` and to split it up to their own properties like this:

```
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38851448"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38853194"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760498"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"39099662"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38855558"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760487"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38760488"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"39099663"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38851450"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
{"s":{"$numberLong":"38853546"},"a":5,"someKey":"someValue"}
```

This way I'm able to import the data like this:

```
mongoimport --type json --db test --collection coll --upsertFields a,s --file test.json
```

with this new documents get inserted and old documents get updated

**UPDATE**:

In [TOOLS-894](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-894) and [TOOLS-899](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-899) the mongodb developers describe another workaround: You can use mongoimport from the 2.6 Version, which didn't have this bug. Or you can wait for mongodb 3.0.7 which should contain the fix.

**UPDATE 2**:

New versions of MongoDB fixed this problem and work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Removing --upsert from your mongoimport command will allow you to import the data. But that reveals another bigger problem - mongoimport does not preserve your _id field's key ordering. Sometimes s comes first, sometimes a. This would make every application operation involving the _id tedious and slow - you can't use a document literal, you would have to use something like:

```
db.coll.find({'_id.a': 5, '_id.s': NumberLong("38760488")})
```

Using an embedded document as _id seems like an edge case and there are no jira issues relating to this. _id types can be anything but an array, so they intended for this use case. Bulk operations use a different mechanism than standard write operations, so... probably a bug - no one else is doing this and discovered it yet?

You could probably work around this using individual write commands (and then use a doc literal as a query param) - but should you? Not being able to use mongo export/import for db maintenance seems like a deal killer to me.

Also note: mongoimport --upsert will replace any existing doc with "someKey":"someValue" - assuming this is just a simplified test case.

You can head over to https://jira.mongodb.org and sign up for an account to report the bug.

Comment: the upsert is necessary, because the JSON-file I get is a dump from another (non-MongoDB) system and contains new and updated documents, so the upsert is mandatory, because without it, it would fail to `import with E11000 duplicate key error collection`. I will try to report this as a bug and also try to find a workaround